# Apply several transformation functions to string

Tags: scala

Suppose I have 2 methods:

```
def a(s: String) = s + "..."

def b(s: String) = s + ",,,"
```

And I want to create 3rd method which will call both methods:

```
def c (s: String) = a(b(s))
```

How I can do it in idiomatic Scala way?

I think it's better to aggregate this functions into some List and then sequentially apply them:

`List(a_, b_)`

Comment: There's probably a million different ways to do it in Scala, [implicits](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-to-add-new-methods-to-existing-classes) being one of them.

Comment: If you want a _method_ `a(b(s))` is a good way. Why do you need something else?

Comment: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html

Comment: Have a look at `andThen` or `compose`.

Answer (score 4):

> I think it's better to aggregate this functions into some List and
>   then sequentially apply them.

You get some help by specifying an expected type:

```
scala> val fs: List[String => String] = List(a,b)
fs: List[String => String] = List(<function1>, <function1>)

scala> fs.foldLeft("something")((s,f) => f(s))
res0: String = something...,,,
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can combine a set of functions into one:

```
// a() and b() are as defined in the question 
// the following is equivalent to newfunc(x) = b(a(x))   
val newFunc: String => String = List( a _, b _).reduce( _ andThen _ )
```

You can even create a generic function to combine them:

```
def functionChaining[A]( functions: A => A *): A => A = functions.reduce( _ andThen _ )
```

or using `foldLeft`:

```
def functionChaining[A]( functions: A => A *): A => A  = functions.foldLeft( (x:A) => x )( _ andThen _ )
```

Here is an example of how to use this on the REPL:

```
scala> val newFunc: String => String = functionChaining( (x:String) => x + "---", (x:String) => x * 4)
scala> newFunc("|")
res12: String = |---|---|---|---
```

Comment: `andThen` will give `b(a(s))`, not `a(b(s))`

Comment: You are right, you can use `compose` instead of `andThen` to get the order you need.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers use `andThen`, but that will be give you

```
b(a(s))
```

Given that you want

```
a(b(s))
```

`compose` is the way to go (well, that or reversing the list, but what's the point?)

```
def c(s: String) = List[String => String](a, b).reduce(_ compose _)(s)
// or alternatively
def c(s: String) = List(a _, b _).reduce(_ compose _)(s)
```

As a result

```
c("foo") // foo,,,...
```

---

Now, speaking of what's idiomatic, I believe that

```
a(b(s))
```

is more idiomatic and readable than

```
List(a _, b _).reduce(_ compose _)(s)
```

This clearly depends on the number of functions you're composing. If you were to have

```
a(b(c(d(e(f(g(h(s))))))))
```

then

```
List[String => String](a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h).reduce(_ compose _)(s)
```

is probably neater and more idiomatic as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* think you need to do this:

```
val c = a _ andThen b

// (The signature is:)
val c:(String)=>String = a _ andThen b
```

or, more obviously:

```
def d(s:String) = a _ andThen b
```

Comment: `andThen` will give `b(a(s))`, not `a(b(s))`

Answer (score 0):

If chained application is preferred then the below works. Caveats - Implicit syntax is a bit ugly; This being a structural type uses reflection.

```
object string {
  implicit def aPimp(s: String) = new {
    def a = "(a- " + s + " -a)"
  }
  implicit def bPimp(s: String) = new {
    def b = "(b- " + s + " -b)"
  }
}

scala> import string._
scala> "xyz".a.b
res0: String = (b- (a- xyz -a) -b)
scala> "xyz".b.a
res1: String = (a- (b- xyz -b) -a)
```

In my opinion, if not for the ugly syntax, this would be idiomatic scala.